# How to compare two Dates in JavaScript with format 2011-jan-21

Tags: javascript, html

Well I know this question is asked a thousand times on internet but I am a rookie and don't know much about Javascript functions. I want to compare two date. 
Input is in form = "2011-jan-21"

Here is what I have come up, Please help! I will really appreciate because I need to get it worked urgently.

```
   function compareDates() {
            var startDate=document.getElementById("startDate").value;
            var endDate = document.getElementById("endDate").value;
                months = {'jan': '01', 'feb': '02', 'mar': '03', 'apr': '04', 'may': '05',
                'jun': '06', 'jul': '07', 'aug': '08', 'sep': '09', 'oct': '10', 'nov': '11',
                'dec': '12'};
                split = startDate.split('-');
                var newStartDate = [split[2], months[split[1]], split[0]].join(',');

                split = endDate.split('-');
                var newEndDate = [split[2], months[split[1]], split[0]].join(',');

                var myDate=new Date();
                myDate.setFullYear(startDate);
                console.log(newStartDate);

                var myDateEnd=new Date();
                myDateEnd.setFullYear(endDate);

             if (myDate < myDateEnd) {
                alert ("Error !");
             }
        }


<form method="POST" id="myForm" onsubmit="compareDates()">
        <input id="startDate" />
        <input id="endDate" />
        <input type="Submit" />

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the string to a `Date` constructor. **Much** easier.

```
var startDate = new Date(document.getElementById("startDate").value);
var endDate = new Date(document.getElementById("endDate").value);
```

Now you've got two [full-fledged `Date` instances](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) that you can work with as you please.

```
function compare()
{
    var startDate = new Date(document.getElementById("startDate").value);
    var endDate = new Date(document.getElementById("endDate").value);

    if (startDate.getTime() > endDate.getTime())
    {
        alert ("Error !");
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean this is what I should do: 
function compare(){
   var startDate = new Date(document.getElementById("startDate").value);
   var endDate = new Date(document.getElementById("endDate").value);
   if (startDate > endDate){
    alert ("Error !");
   }
  }

Its not working !

Comment: Working like a charm! Thank you Matt.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do with them is compare them, I wouldn't even bother with encoding them as dates, since the year, month, and day fields are already in most-significant to least-significant order.  If you can parse out the year, the month (in numerical form; 0-origin or 1-origin is OK, as long as you remain consistent), and the day, in the order given, then you can compute an integer `i = (year * 10000)+(month * 100)+day`.

Given both dates are so converted, you can use the normal equality and ordering operators (==, <, >=, etc.) as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
if (myDate.getTime() < myDateEnd.getTime()) 
{
    alert ("Error !");
}
```